# Customize jQuery stack chart

Tags: jquery, charts, canvasjs

I am trying to plot users vs work performance as bar chart. I can implement this as stack chart using canvasjs.com as,[image]

But I have to split each section based on the time. So I have to implement the chart something like,[image]

Is there any way to customize the chart
Or is there any jQuery library available for this

If this is a duplicate question, please forgive me I dont know how to search this in google. And sorry for my bad language.

Comment: In my experience no chart library supports repeated colors in stacked column or bar charts. If you can live with using different colors for the stacked elements, [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent) would be an option. It's free for non-commercial and well affordable for most other user groups.

Comment: Do you really mean repeated colors or do you mean something else? If its repeated colors, you can add colorSet with only 2 colors using [addColorSet](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/colorset/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using google charts, you can use multiple series (data table columns),
to create the chart.

use the `series` option to set the color for each,
and hide the duplicate legend entries.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Anthracite', 'Lignite', 'Anthracite', 'Lignite', 'Anthracite', 'Lignite'],
    ['USA', 50000, 20000, 50000, 20000, 50000, 20000],
    ['Russia', 40000, 25000, 30000, 15000, 50000, 23000],
    ['China', 12000, 26000, 51000, 24000, 51000, 22000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    series: {
      0: {  // Anthracite 1
        color: 'blue'
      },
      1: {  // Lignite 1
        color: 'red'
      },
      2: {  // Anthracite 2
        color: 'blue',
        visibleInLegend: false
      },
      3: {  // Lignite 2
        color: 'red',
        visibleInLegend: false
      },
      4: {  // Anthracite 3
        color: 'blue',
        visibleInLegend: false
      },
      5: {  // Lignite 3
        color: 'red',
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```